# Where do I get the source for ESM packages?

Tags: apt, updates, esm

My home server is running Ubuntu 22.04 (Jammy) and is enrolled in Ubuntu Pro.

```bash
alan@earth:~$ pro status
SERVICE          ENTITLED  STATUS    DESCRIPTION
esm-apps         yes       enabled   Expanded Security Maintenance for Applications
esm-infra        yes       enabled   Expanded Security Maintenance for Infrastructure
livepatch        yes       enabled   Canonical Livepatch service
realtime-kernel  yes       disabled  Ubuntu kernel with PREEMPT_RT patches integrated

Enable services with: pro enable <service>

     Account: (my email here)
Subscription: Ubuntu Pro - free personal subscription
```

I have received an update to one or more packages via ESM.

```bash
alan@earth:~$ dpkg -l  | grep esm
ii  imagemagick                            8:6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3ubuntu0.22.04.1+esm1 amd64        image manipulation programs -- binaries
ii  imagemagick-6-common                   8:6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3ubuntu0.22.04.1+esm1 all          image manipulation programs -- infrastructure
ii  imagemagick-6.q16                      8:6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3ubuntu0.22.04.1+esm1 amd64        image manipulation programs -- quantum depth Q16
ii  libmagickcore-6.q16-6:amd64            8:6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3ubuntu0.22.04.1+esm1 amd64        low-level image manipulation library -- quantum depth Q16
ii  libmagickcore-6.q16-6-extra:amd64      8:6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3ubuntu0.22.04.1+esm1 amd64        low-level image manipulation library - extra codecs (Q16)
ii  libmagickwand-6.q16-6:amd64            8:6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3ubuntu0.22.04.1+esm1 amd64        image manipulation library -- quantum depth Q16
ii  libopenexr25:amd64                     2.5.7-1ubuntu0.1~esm1                    amd64        runtime files for the OpenEXR image library
```

For example, libopenexr25:

```bash
alan@earth:~$ apt-cache policy libopenexr25
libopenexr25:
  Installed: 2.5.7-1ubuntu0.1~esm1
  Candidate: 2.5.7-1ubuntu0.1~esm1
  Version table:
 *** 2.5.7-1ubuntu0.1~esm1 500
        500 https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu jammy-apps-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.5.7-1 500
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages
```

I would like the source for these. I have the source lines in my relavent sources.list files.

```bash
alan@earth:~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-esm-*
deb https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu jammy-apps-security main
deb-src https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu jammy-apps-security main
deb https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu jammy-apps-updates main
deb-src https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu jammy-apps-updates main
deb https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu jammy-infra-security main
deb-src https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu jammy-infra-security main
deb https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu jammy-infra-updates main
deb-src https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu jammy-infra-updates main
```

Yet when I try to download the source, I get a 401 error.

```bash
alan@earth:~/foo$ apt source libopenexr25
Reading package lists... Done
Picking 'openexr' as source package instead of 'libopenexr25'
NOTICE: 'openexr' packaging is maintained in the 'Git' version control system at:
https://salsa.debian.org/debian-phototools-team/openexr.git
Please use:
git clone https://salsa.debian.org/debian-phototools-team/openexr.git
to retrieve the latest (possibly unreleased) updates to the package.
Need to get 27.6 MB of source archives.
Err:1 https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu jammy-apps-security/main openexr 2.5.7-1ubuntu0.1~esm1 (tar)
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 185.125.190.23 443]
Err:2 https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu jammy-apps-security/main openexr 2.5.7-1ubuntu0.1~esm1 (asc)
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 185.125.190.23 443]
Err:3 https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu jammy-apps-security/main openexr 2.5.7-1ubuntu0.1~esm1 (diff)
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 185.125.190.23 443]
Err:4 https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu jammy-apps-security/main openexr 2.5.7-1ubuntu0.1~esm1 (dsc)
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 185.125.190.23 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openexr/openexr_2.5.7.orig.tar.gz  401  Unauthorized [IP: 185.125.190.23 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openexr/openexr_2.5.7.orig.tar.gz.asc  401  Unauthorized [IP: 185.125.190.23 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openexr/openexr_2.5.7-1ubuntu0.1%7eesm1.debian.tar.xz  401  Unauthorized [IP: 185.125.190.23 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openexr/openexr_2.5.7-1ubuntu0.1%7eesm1.dsc  401  Unauthorized [IP: 185.125.190.23 443]
```

How do I get these source files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Access is protected by a token stored in a file inside /etc/apt/auth.conf.d. that file is not readable by normal users, so you have to use sudo or otherwise run the download as root, or give your user permission to read that snippet (but not sure yet if the pro client preserves it).

Comment: `sudo chmod a+r /etc/apt/auth.conf.d/90ubuntu-advantage` does the trick. So far nothing has complained about it. And I don't think from my perspective that password is particularly valuable.