other orkaround for OpenSSH CVE-2023-48795 instead of package update?
Execuse me,
I'm currently maintaining an ubuntu 18 operating system which is isolated from internet and has difficulty on package update or dirstribution upgrade.
There's OpenSSH installed and running on this ubuntu and is detected by scanning tool that the CVE-2023-48795 is affecting it.
According to ubuntu official statement https://ubuntu.com/security/CVE-2023-48795 ,this vulnerability can be fixed with patch "7.6p1-4ubuntu0.7+esm3" apparently. (Or upgrade to a newer distribution)
However, due to restrictions in the environment, I have to find other methods to solve CVE-2023-48795 rather than package patching.
Does anyone know how to fix CVE-2023-48795 on OpenSSH please?
Any configurations to change?

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS reached End of Standard Support last year, and is thus off-topic on this site.  You can use ESM/Pro support options (cost maybe involved) if you wish but community support (such as this site) no longer exists, though SE Unix & Linux allow all Ubuntu questions too.  Please see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic as Canonical provide ESM/Pro services.

The fix you provided wasn't patch details; but the actual package version which contains the fix. You just upgrade your packages & install that package in the normal upgrade process (with ESM).

FYI:  This question (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1454409/where-do-i-get-the-source-for-esm-packages) maybe useful if you're willing to build your own packages...
